# Issue With Laravel View/Blade & React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, components, laravel-blade, server-side-rendering

After using the `php artisan preset react` command my app couldn't render React app components; the page is blank. I started my PHP server using `php artisan serve` and started Node with `npm run dev.`

**app.blade.php**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is running without any errors.

## EDIT.

I changed Example.js inside assets/js/components to App.js => code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
    import Header from './Header'

    class App extends Component {
      render () {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Header/>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to export the component as `export default App;`